# Basic Pandas matplotlib plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Sorry to ask such a basic question, but after hours (and hours) of frustration I'm turning to the list for some expert help.

I have two pandas dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. `df1` has columns A and B, while `df2` has columns C and D. I want to use matplotlib to make a scatterplot of A vs. B, with labelled axes, and a histogram of C, also with a title on the x axis. Then I want to save both figures in pdf files.

I can accomplish the former with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(df1['A'],df1['B'])
plt.xlabel('X title')
plt.ylabel('Y title')
plt.savefig('myfig1.pdf')
```

But I can't get the histogram to work, and if it does, it creates a graph with both the scatterplot and the histogram in it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `plt.hist(df3[C'])`? What's the error message with the histogram creation?

Comment: I get a long series of errors, ending with "KeyError: 0"

Comment: what kind of data is in df2['C'] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to make another figure for the histogram,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df1['A'],df1['B'])
plt.xlabel('X title')
plt.ylabel('Y title')
plt.savefig('myfig1.pdf')

fig2 = plt.figure()
... <histogram code>
```

Or you can assign the axes to variables so you dont have to do everything in order,

```
import random
x = [random.random() for i in range(50)]
y = [random.random() for i in range(50)]

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)

ax1.scatter( x, y )
ax1.set_xlabel('X title')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y title')
fig1.savefig('myfig1.pdf')

ax2.hist( y )
```

Note that when setting properties of an axis using its methods, most of the `plt` attributes become `set_X`.  For example, instead of `plt.ylabel('my_y')` you do `ax1.set_ylabel('my_y')`.  You can still use the `plt` methods, but they will apply to whatever the current plot is.  The variables `ax1` and `ax2` give you a little more freedom about when you do things.

Comment: Thanks very much Gabriel. I can get the scatterplot to work with the fig, ax method. And I can get the histogram to work with the regular plt.hist() method, if I use `df2['C'].values` as the argument. But the histograms with fig, ax seem to be a problem, even with the `values` included.

Comment: what does typing df2['C'].values into an ipython session give you?  what kind of data is it?

Comment: It gives me `array([ 0.81132075,  0.73684211,  0.22222222, ...,  0.72727273, 0.625,  0.42857143])`.

Comment: You know, it's possible that the problem is the IDE I'm using, which is Spyder. I tried just doing a basic histogram from the matplotlib documentation, and that didn't even work with the fig, ax notation.

Comment: yes, an array shouldn't give `plt.hist` or `ax2.hist` any problems unless there are some corrupted values in the array.  Any NaNs or similar?

Comment: No, the array itself is clean. Sigh. What IDE do you use for python? I may just have to ditch Spyder.

Comment: can you verify that an array you create on the fly works with `hist`? Instead of `df2['C']` try using `np.arange(50)` then you can narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: OK, let me check... Running out of power, will have to get to an outlet.

Comment: Also, if my answer helped you solve your problem can you click the green check to accept it, thanks.

Comment: @DavidEpstein your matplotlib or ipython install might be corrupted if some basic matplotlib commands don't work.  Spyder just uses an ipython qtconsole session, so don't give up on the whole IDE until you figure out exactly the problem :)